# (A modification to) Jon Pérez Laraudogoita’s "Beautiful Supertask" — What assumptions of Noether's theorem fail?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, hamiltonian-formalism, noethers-theorem, complex-systems

I am curious about the following (physically unrealizable) scenario involving a supertask described here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-supertasks/#ClasMechSupe. The original paper is https://www.jstor.org/stable/2254538.

From the first link, we consider infinitely many pool balls lined up along the $x$-axis. We'll take the balls as points particles, one situated at $x_{0}=-1$, another at $x_{1}=-1/2$, another at $x_{1}=-1/4$, and so on (with no final particle). Assume the particles are all of equal mass.

The description is as follows.

> Suppose an infinite lattice of particles of the same mass are arranged so that there is a distance of ½ between the first and the second, a distance of ¼ between the second and the third, a distance of ⅛ between the third and the fourth, and so on. Now imagine that a new particle of the same mass collides with the first particle in the lattice, as in Figure 1.4.1. If it is a perfectly elastic collision, then the incoming particle will come to rest and the velocity will be transferred to the struck particle. Suppose it takes ½ of a second for the second collision to occur. Then it will take ¼ of a second for the third to occur, ⅛ of a second for the fourth, and so on. The entire infinite process will thus be completed after 1 second.

Now the interesting feature of this system of infinitely many particles is that the system displays a failure of conservation of energy.

> Earman and Norton (1998) observed several curious facts about this system. [...] Third, although energy is conserved in each local collision, the global energy of this system is not conserved, since after finite time it becomes a lattice of infinitely many particles all at rest. [...] The failure of global energy conservation and other curious features of this system have been studied by Atkinson (2007, 2008), Atkinson and Johnson (2009, 2010) and by Peijnenburg and Atkinson (2008) and Atkinson and Peijnenburg (2014).

### Question

In this scenario, energy conservation appears to be violated even though the Hamiltonian ought to be time-translation invariant.
It seems some subtle assumption of Noether's theorem is violated.

Can anyone explain what subtle assumption of Noether's theorem is violated? Obviously, the problem is that we have a system of infinitely many particles, yes, but where exactly does this pose a problem for Noether's theorem and its proof? Where is the pathology exactly?

Please note my question is more about the mathematics rather than the physics, although some physical intuition helps.

Below I'll modify the scenario so that we take out the instantaneous collisions and replace them by repulsive interactions. Then I'll write out the Hamiltonian as an infinite sum of terms. This may or may not change the scenario (really this is just to take out the Dirac delta terms out of the Hamiltonian in case anyone might think they're pathological).

### First Case: Two Balls

First, I will present a warm-up to describe the kind of interaction I want between the particles. Given two particles long the $x$-axis, I propose the potential energy function

\begin{align}\tag{1}
U(x_{1}, x_{2}) = \begin{cases} A(1 - B|x_{2}-x_{1}|), & x_{2}-x_{1}\in[-\frac{1}{B}, \frac{1}{B}], \\
0, & \text{else} \end{cases} 
\end{align}

where $A, B$ are positive constants. (In Case 2, these will not necessarily be the same for each pair of particles.)

Suppose we send particle $1$ with velocity $v_{0}$ at the stationary particle $2$ at $x_{2}=0$, both particles are of mass $m$, and the $v_{0}$ is such that $A = \frac{1}{2}mv_{0}^{2}$. The solution to our system is

$$ x_{1}(t) = \begin{cases} -\frac{1}{B} + v_{0}t, & t < 0, \\
-\frac{1}{B} + v_{0}t - \frac{1}{2}\frac{AB}{m}t^{2}, & t\in [0, \frac{mv_{0}}{AB}], \\
0, & t > \frac{mv_{0}}{AB} \end{cases} $$

and

$$ x_{2}(t) = \begin{cases} 0, & t < 0, \\
\frac{1}{2}\frac{AB}{m}t^{2}, & t\in [0, \frac{mv_{0}}{AB}], \\
v_{0}t, & t > \frac{mv_{0}}{AB}, \end{cases} $$

so the first particle transfers all its kinetic energy to the second particle and takes the second particle's position, so the scenario effectively is like an elastic collision. The interaction takes place within the spatial interval of width
$$ \Delta x = 2/B $$
and time interval
$$ \Delta t = mv_{0}/AB = 2/v_{0}B = \Delta x/v_{0}$$
where $B > 0$ can be arbitrarily large. This will be used for the next case.

### Second Case: Infinitely Many Balls

Now let us return to our original scenario of infinitely many particles. Our initial conditions involve particles $-1, 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ with initial positions

$$ x_{-1}(0) = -2,\quad x_{0}(0) = -1,\quad  x_{1}(0) = -1/2,\quad  x_{2}(0) = -1/4,\quad  x_{3}(0) = -1/8,\quad \ldots $$

and initial velocities

$$ \dot{x}_{-1}(0) = v_{0} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \dot{x}_{k}(0) = 0 \quad (k\ge 0) $$

where $v_{0} > 0$. Now suppose this system has a Hamiltonian

$$ H = \sum_{k=-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}_{k}^{2} + \sum_{i < j} U_{ij}(x_{i}, x_{j}) $$

where $U_{ij}$ is the potential given by $(1)$ with $A_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}mv_{0}^{2}$ and $B_{ij} = 2^{2^{j+1}}$ where again $i < j$. During the evolution of the system, no more than two particles are directly interacting with each other, because the interaction between particle $i$ and particle $j$ ($i < j$) has range $\Delta x = 2/B_{ij}$. The energy is transferred across all the particles within a finite time interval, because each interaction takes place for a time $\Delta t = 2/v_{0}B_{ij}$ and $\sum_{k} 2/v_{0}B_{k, k+1} < \infty$.

Now we can consider the scenario the same way as in the link. At time $t=0$, the total energy is nonzero, because the $-1$ particle has a velocity $v_{0}$. It sends all its kinetic energy to particle $0$ and takes the place of the initial position of particle $0$. Particle $0$ then sends all its kinetic energy to particle $1$ and takes the place of the initial position of particle $1$. Particle $1$ then sends all its kinetic energy to particle $2$ and takes the place of the initial position of particle $2$. This process repeats ad infinitum but it takes place within a finite time span! At the end, after a sufficiently large time interval, we will have

$$ x_{-1}(T) = -1,\quad x_{0}(T) = -1/2,\quad x_{1}(T) = -1/4,\quad  x_{2}(T) = -1/8,\quad x_{3}(T) = -1/16,\quad \ldots $$

with all particles having velocity zero. Thus, energy dropped from $E = \frac{1}{2}mv_{0}^{2}$ to $E = 0$. This system violated energy conservation. However, the Hamiltonian is time-translation invariant, because it has no explicit time-dependence.

### Some Non-Answers

- The fact that I used a non-differentiable function for the potential in $(1)$ is not an issue, because it can be approximated by a smooth / infinitely differentiable function to arbitrary precision. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4546655.
- The setup of the problem specifically involves a classical system, meaning the underlying space is continuous and trajectories are well-defined and continuous. We can reformulate the system as a set of infinitely many differentiable equations if we wish.
- By the setup of the problem, there is no particle $\infty$ at $x=0$ nor is there any reason for such a particle to appear.

All I'm asking is, how does Noether's theorem figure into a Hamiltonian system of infinitely many particles? Where does the generalization fail? It's a pretty simple question.

Comment: How do you avoid the black hole at x=0?

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4742257/11127

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the given scenario, the derivation of Noether's theorem is very simple. Let's have a look at what goes wrong.

In your question, you describe an infinite number of particles with positions $\mathbf x = (x_1, x_2, \dots)$. The Lagrange function $L(\mathbf x, \dot{\mathbf x})$ is a function of infinitely many variables, but that is not a problem per se. In your question, you describe curves $\mathbf x(t)$ that solve the Euler-Lagrange equation $\partial_{\mathbf x} L = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \partial_{\dot{\mathbf x}} L$ at each time $t$, but violate energy conservation.

The usual proof of energy conservation is simply this:
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} L(\mathbf x, \dot{\mathbf x}) = \dot{\mathbf x} \cdot \partial_{\mathbf x} L(\mathbf x, \dot{\mathbf x}) + \ddot{\mathbf x} \cdot \partial_{\dot{\mathbf x}} L(\mathbf x, \dot{\mathbf x}) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \bigl( \dot{\mathbf x} \cdot \partial_{\dot{\mathbf x}} L(\mathbf x, \dot{\mathbf x}) \bigr) , $$
therefore $\bigl(\dot{\mathbf x} \cdot \partial_{\dot{\mathbf x}} L(\mathbf x, \dot{\mathbf x}) - L(\mathbf x, \dot{\mathbf x})\bigr)$ is constant.
The first equality is the chain rule, the second equality follows from the Euler-Lagrange equation.

At this point I have to make a quick remark: in your example, $\dot{\mathbf x}$ is not differentiable, which makes the derivation look problematic. However, $\dot{\mathbf x}$ is weakly differentiable, and we can save the derivation by interpreting $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}$ and the dots as weak derivatives. Note that if the weak derivative of a function is zero, then that function is constant (more precisely: takes the same constant value almost everywhere).

What we have seen so far leads me to conclude that the hidden assumption that is violated in your example must be the following: that plugging (weakly) differentiable $\mathbf x(t)$ and $\dot{\mathbf x}(t)$ into $L$ would lead to a (weakly) differentiable $L(\mathbf x(t), \dot{\mathbf x}(t))$. Indeed, by plugging in your solutions, we can verify that this expression is not weakly differentiable here. Let $T$ be the time after which no particle is moving, then
$$ L(\mathbf x(t), \dot{\mathbf x}(t)) = \begin{cases} \frac{mv_0^2}{2} & t < T \\ 0 & t \geq T \end{cases} . $$
Of course, the violation of this assumption ultimately comes from the infinite number of particles. If $L$ was a reasonable function of a finite number of degrees of freedom, the composition of $L$ with (weakly) differentiable functions would be (weakly) differentiable itself.

Answer (score 20):

Consider the simpler problem: a particle of mass $m_1$ moving at a speed of $v_1$ undergoes an elastic collision with a stationary ($v_2=0$) extended body of *infinite* mass $m_2$. What happens?

(The collection of infinitely many particles all of the same, non-zero mass can be considered collectively as a single body of infinite mass.)

Conservation of momentum says $m_1v_1'+m_2v_2'=m_1v_1+m_2v_2$. We can rearrange this as $m_1/m_2=(v_2'-v_2)/(v_1'-v_1)$. When $m_1/m_2=0$, we get $v_2'-v_2=0$, and the infinite mass's centre of mass does not move. Then $0=0/(v_1'-v_1)$ and so $v_1'-v_1=0/0$ which is indeterminate. *Any* value we put in here satisfies conservation of momentum.

The same thing happens with $\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1'^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2'^2=\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2$. It's just slightly messier.

An infinite mass that is moving has *infinite* momentum and kinetic energy. An infinite mass that is stationary has *indeterminate* momentum and kinetic energy. In either case, you can add or subtract any finite amount of momentum/energy and it remains infinite/indeterminate. Just because the velocity is zero doesn't imply the kinetic energy or momentum is zero.

This sort of indeterminacy can occur in classical mechanics any time we set mass to zero or infinity. The flaw isn't to do with Noether's theorem, or the details of the supertask. It's just the ordinary nonsensical consequences of dividing by zero.

Comment: This is the correct answer when the total mass is infinite, but the problem still seems interesting when the total mass is finite. I glanced at the first paper by Atkinson that was mentioned in the SEP article and he only considers systems of finite total mass. On the other hand he incorrectly says that the total momentum in the infinite-mass case is zero, so maybe he overlooked something in the rest of the paper also.

Comment: *Consider the simpler problem* … *body of infinite mass* … How is this *simpler*? I do not know how to write nontrivial Lagrangian/Hamiltonian for a single body of infinite mass, do you?

Comment: @benrg Infinite mass (or infinite number of masses) cannot be the correct answer, since the energy does not disappear from e.g. infinite 1D crystal lattice composed of the same masses with the same spring constants between neighbors. To me the OP's formalization of the paradox resembles a discretization of wave propagation in AdS space, where energy can leave the universe in finite time, so I would have wanted criteria that resemble concepts of lorentzian causality.

Comment: @A.V.S. I think your reasoning is backwards. When the energy is ill-defined, anything may happen, including nothing at all. It means that you shouldn't be surprised if something odd happens, not that you should be surprised if it doesn't. The infinite lattice is probably well-behaved because it's a limit of finite lattices, while there doesn't seem to be a behavior-preserving limit for this problem. Anyway, I meant to say with my comment that infinite mass indeed isn't the answer because the paradox can be formulated without it (at least according to Atkinson).

Answer (score 6):

As long as you've got your infinitely many particles close at hand, here is a simpler experiment:   pile them all up on the left side of your desk (there's room for them because each has half the diameter of the last).  At time $-1$, move balls number 1 through 10 to the right side of your desk and then remove ball 1.   At time $-1/2$, move balls 11 to 20 to the right side and then remove ball 2.  At time $-1/4$, move balls 21 to 30 the right side and then remove ball 3.....

The mass on the right side of your desk is positive just after time $-1$, there is never any moment at which it decreases, and yet it is $0$ at time $1$.  Surely you can spin this as a failure of conversation of mass (and hence of energy).

The point is that there is not much physics going on in this version of the story, yet it yields exactly the same paradox as your version does.  All of the stuff about Hamiltonians, etc., was unnecessary.  Which suggests that the "paradox" is not fundamentally about physics.

In fact, your experiment is certainly non-physical in that (for one thing) it requires balls of arbitrarily high density (since they all have the same mass but their diameters go to zero).

Comment: Can you formalize your “simpler experiment” via a Lagrangian? In that case it would be about physics. … *your experiment is certainly non-physical*… The question is about Lagrangian mechanics, so which features of the presented Lagrangian are unphysical?

Comment: @A.V.S. :  The point of my answer is that Lagrangian mechanics, despite appearances, is not the source of ths paradox here.

Comment: @NulliusInVerbia 's fabulous answer makes essentially the same point:  The source of the paradox is the infinite mass, not anything about the Lagrangian.

Answer (score 3):

I endorse Nullius in Verba's and WillO’s  answers as correct but do think they are missing some of the spirit of the question, namely where exactly does the proof of Noether's theorem go wrong in this case? Let's examine the following special case of Noether's theorem first for finitely many particles then for infinitely many particles. If we have $N$ particles $x_1,x_2,\dots x_N$ with the Lagrangian
$$L=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{2}\dot{x_i}^2-U(x_1,\dots x_N)$$
then the  energy
$$E=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{2}\dot{x_i}^2+U(x_1,\dots x_N)$$
is conserved.
Lets proof this:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}E&=\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{2}\dot{x_i}^2+\frac{d}{dt}U(x_1,\dots x_N) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^N\dot{x_i}\ddot{x_i}+\frac{d}{dt}U(x_1,\dots x_N)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^N\dot{x_i}\ddot{x_i}+\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}U(x_1,\dots x_N)\dot{x_i}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^N(\ddot{x_i}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}U(x_1,\dots x_N))\dot{x_i}\\
&=0
\end{align}$$
where the last line uses the equation of motion $\ddot{x_i}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}U$.

So, where can this go wrong if $N=\infty$? There are a couple of possible issues. Firstly in line 2 we used $\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i=1}\frac{1}{2}\dot{x_i}^2=\sum_{i=1}\dot{x_i}\ddot{x_i}$ i.e. we interchanged the derivative and the summation. This is of course justified for finite sums but it may be the case that $$\frac{d}{dt}\sum_n^\infty f_n(t)=\sum_n^\infty \frac{d}{dt} f_n(t)$$ in untrue if $$\sum_n^\infty \frac{d}{dt} f_n(t)$$ doesn’t converge uniformly. This is exactly what happens in the example in the question where the sum $\sum_{i=1}\dot{x_i}\ddot{x_i}$ does not converge uniformly in any interval containing $0$.

The equation
$$\frac{d}{dt}U(x_1,\dots )=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}U(x_1,\dots )\dot{x_i}$$ may also fail as it requires certain conditions on $U$ and $\dot{x_i}$.

Physics routinely apply Noether’s theorem to systems with infinitely many degrees of freedom and don’t pay these issues any mind as they only come up in unphysical situations.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing only the initial, textbook case:

The primary issue comes from the fact that time is indexed with the reals but the particles are indexed with the naturals, and, as proven with Cantor's diagonalization argument, the cardinality of the naturals is less than that of the reals. i.e. there are less natural numbers than real numbers. Furthermore, by the same argument, it's been proven that any closed interval with unequal bounds has cardinality equal to that of the reals. i.e. there are as many reals within an interval on the real line, such as from x=-1 to x=0, as there are on the entire line. As will be outlined more below, this thought experiment really just concerns the same problems with infinities that mathematics faced in the early 20th century.

Given that they are all identical point particles and that each collision is perfectly elastic, the scenario is truly no different than observing a single particle pass from x=-1 to x=0 in 1 second. The scenario of infinitely many identical particles placed at -(1/2)^n for each natural number n is as if taking the individual particle and looking at each (1/2)^n'th snapshot of it as a collision with itself. The collisions don't effect the particle's motion towards x=0 in any way, they're simply an inefficient, unclear way of conceptualizing that motion. Similarly, we pass through these snapshots each second as well, but our universe still holds that energy is conserved.

You could consider this is a more mathematical way of justifying the planck scale, in that the planck time and planck length must exist such that time and length do not have larger indices than that of the things they are measuring. i.e. if we are measuring the time of something discrete and countable, then time itself ought to be discrete and countable. Of course, this is a more debatable statement to make, and there are many disagreeing ideas of how physics behaves at the planck scale, but I believe this is still an interesting thing to note and gives context of this thought experiment in terms of reality.

In short, once a second has passed, a particle will shoot out from x=0 towards positive infinity with the same energy and momentum the initial particle entered the lattice with, just like an individual particle passing over the same interval would. Thus, the law of conservation of energy holds.

Comment: Which particle comes out the other end?

Comment: @DavidHartley The "last" one. Of course there is no last one in the way we want to think about it, but it's true that one would "run out" of natural numbers before one runs out of real numbers. In terms of ordinals, the "omega"-th particle would be the one to come out the other end.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with the conclusion of the initial problem statement. The particle that was originally at zero, i.e. $x_\infty(t=0)=0$ will be the one left moving rightwards with $\dot x_\infty(t\geqslant T)=v_0$ and so energy will be conserved.

It is way too easy to get caught up in such contrived situations and deliberately fail to consider all the conserved quantities. It is probably fun to play with these when the problem is more interesting, but this is not that interesting.

---

I also have to point out that if you chose the potential to be as you have done, the maximal PE is just equal to the initial KE, then you are courting quantum corrections. It is the situation where quantum corrections will be most severe.

---

You have also chosen the PE function $U_{ij}$ to be such that there is a dependence upon the range $\frac1B$, and for any finite $B>0$ then you cannot ever choose there to be infinitely many particles in this scheme. Even at $t=0$ there will be an infinitely tail of particles near zero that will be closer to each other than $\frac1B$ and thus start moving before the first particle has come into contact with the second particle.

The scenario will only be doable with point particles having billiard ball type collisions. But then my objection right at the top will still apply, because I did not assume much of the scenario.

Comment: Ok, an initial thought: in the scenario there is no particle at $x=0$. The set of particles is infinite but there is no one with a maximum position. Consider the analogy to  intervals in real analysis: the interval $[-1, 0)$ has no maximum point (although it has a least upperbound). Likewise, $\{-1, -1/2, -1/4, \ldots\}$ has no maximum point.

Comment: … *and so energy will be conserved* There is no particle $x_\infty$, there are only particles $x_1$, $x_2$, … indexed by natural numbers, but $\infty$ is not a natural number.

Comment: The physically sensible way to approach this is $\lim_{N\to\infty} x_N$, and this is not missing. That is, the physically sensible approach to infinity should be conserving energy and final particle motion. If you choose for the final particle to be missing, then the situation is no longer physical.

Comment: _"You have also chosen the PE function $U_{ij}$ to be such that there is a dependence upon the range $\frac1B$, and for any finite $B>0$ then you cannot ever choose there to be infinitely many particles in this scheme."_ I did address this by making sure each $U_{ij}$ has a different $B_{ij}$ with $B_{ij} = 2^{2^{j}}$. In my post, _"During the evolution of the system, no more than two particles are directly interacting with each other, because the interaction between particle $i$ and particle $j$ ($i < j$) has range $\Delta x = 2/B_{ij}$."_

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that, but it just removes that part.